# Click on UIButton Does Not Work if it's Added as Subview to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, addsubview

I have a simple `UIImageView` that is animated, and i need to detect a tap on it. I've added a `UIButton` that is a subview of this `UIImageView`. However,the tap on it does not work. I've already tested the `UIButton` itself when added to the view,and it works, so it's not the button that is causing the problem.

Here's the code:

```
self.red = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 300, 85, 100)];
self.red.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];

[self.red setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
[self.view addSubview: self.red];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.red]; 

UIButton *redButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
redButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.red.frame.origin.x, self.red.frame.origin.y, self.red.frame.size.width, self.red.frame.size.height);
[redButton addTarget: self action:@selector(correctButtonClick) forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
[redButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.red addSubview: redButton];
[self.red bringSubviewToFront:redButton];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using a scroll view?

Comment: just update your button frame.. x and y should be 0,0

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this line , `redButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.red.frame.origin.x, self.red.frame.origin.y, self.red.frame.size.width, self.red.frame.size.height);` try this

```
redButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.red.frame.size.width, self.red.frame.size.height);
```

**EDIT :** This line `[self.red bringSubviewToFront:redButton];` is no needed..

Comment: It's a good idea, but it does not help. Could it be that it has anything to do with the fact that the UIImageView is animated?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inserting a `UIButton` as a subview use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, for example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(correctButtonClick)];
[self.red addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is to invert your implementation, adding UIButton to UIImageView is not a good idea, rather create a custom styled UIButton programatically, and add UIImageView as its subview, would definitely work

EDIT:
As for you current implementation, youve added UIButton inside a UIImageView so probably you want every part of image to accept the click event, in that case your x and y coords of UIButton would be 0,0 rather than red.x and red.y, however width and height are correct

Comment: Yep, it does not work. Like I said, the button it self is on the right place and has the right size when added to the view. When added as a subview to UIImaggeView, it does not work. When i reversed the implementation (UIImage added to UIButton) it works when it's not animated, but when I animate it, it does not react on taps.

Comment: in that case it doesnt react on taps, try using tapGestureRecognizer

Comment: how about completely removing uibutton, and use UIImageView with tapgesturerecognizer..

Comment: I also tried that, but it does not work:

`self.red = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 300, 85, 100)];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(correctButtonClick)];

  [self.red addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    
    self.red.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];

    self.red.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 
    [self.view addSubview: self.red];`

Answer (score 1):

Just do self.red.userInteractionEnabled = YES.

UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled NO as default.

Comment: if you take a look the question you will see that he doing this already `[self.red setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];`

Comment: see this line `[self.red setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];` in above code?

Answer (score 1):

The custom button has no UI. So you can't select it. (you can try it with bound button , or add some image to button and set button alpha to 0.1 or else)

@tkanzakic answer should be correct.
Just add TapGestureRecognizer to ImageView or add Image to Button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using separate imageview and Button, **make use of the imageview property within the Button**. Which will solve all your problems and relieves you from writing extra lines of code.

```
UIButton *redButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

> **redButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];**

```
redButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 300, 85, 100);
[redButton addTarget: self action:@selector(correctButtonClick) forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
[redButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.red addSubview: redButton];
```

Comment: I've tried this, but when the button is animated, it still does not react on taps. I need a UIImageView or a UIButton animated (an image is flying from the bottom of the screen to the top).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, the button doesn't respond because its frame is wrong and so it's not where you think it is. Basically change your line below:

```
redButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.red.frame.origin.x, self.red.frame.origin.y, self.red.frame.size.width, self.red.frame.size.height);
```

with this:

```
redButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.red.bounds.origin.x, self.red.bounds.origin.y, self.red.frame.size.width, self.red.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: No, this does not help. When i add UIButton as a subview to the view, then it works, it's right behind the UIImage view, but when I add it as a subview to UIImageView, it does not. I need it to be a subview of  UIImageView, because UIImageView is later on animated.